# Hacer login con firebase pasando por un interceptor (angular)

Tags: angular, firebase

tengo el siguiente interceptor:

```
constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.spinner.show();
    console.log('Se abre el spinner');
    this.cont++;
    return next.handle(request).pipe(finalize( () => {
      this.cont--;
      if (this.cont === 0){
        this.spinner.hide();
        console.log('Se cierra el spinner');
      }
    }));
  }
```

y necesito que cuando hago el logado en firebase entre en el interceptor para que se me muestre el spinner. Este es el metodo de login con firebase:

```
try{
      const result = await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      return result;
    }
    catch (error){
      console.log(error);
    }
```

creo que el fallo esta que afAuth es de AngularFireAuth y no de HttpClient.
Hay alguna forma de que tambien entre en el interceptor para mostrarme el spinner??

Answer (score 0):

Podrías activar el spinner en el mismo lugar donde se hace el login.

```
   try{

      this.spinner.show();
    
      const result = await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      return result;
    }
    catch (error){
      console.log(error);
    }
    finally{
      this.spinner.hide();
   }
```